LibreOffice Writer - How do I add a custom Paper Size?
I am trying to set up to print on envelopes for cards - Dimensions are 5.25 x 7.5 inches, or 133 x 185 mm.
I edited and added this dimension as a defined size to my PPD file - And it shows up in the printer paper size options.

However, when I go to libreoffice print menu, it is missing the size.

How do I add this option to LO so I can print without kludging it?
Ok, so further updates. I figured out some errors I had in the PPD file.
CardEnv/Card Envelope 525x725: is my entry
The problem is now that it doesn't print centered. It prints, as if a letter sheet with the paper bottom left instead of centered (the manual feed prints centered).
How do I adjust the file to have the printer to print centered?
*PPD-Adobe: "4.3"

*%================================================
*%  Copyright(C) 2018 Brother Industries, Ltd.
*%  "Brother MFC-L3750CDW for CUPS"
*%================================================ 

*%==== General Information Keywords ========================
*FormatVersion: "4.3"
*FileVersion: "4.0.9"
*LanguageVersion: English
*LanguageEncoding: ISOLatin1
*PCFileName: "MFC3750W.PPD"
*Manufacturer: "Brother"
*Product: "(MFC-L3750CDW)"
*1284DeviceID: "MFG:Brother;MDL:MFC-L3750CDW"
*cupsVersion: 1.4
*cupsManualCopies: false
*cupsFilter: "application/vnd.cups-postscript 0 brother_lpdwrapper_mfcl3750cdw"
*%cupsFilter: "application/vnd.cups-pdf 0 brother_lpdwrapper_mfcl3750cdw"
*cupsModelNumber: 5
*ModelName: "Brother MFC-L3750CDW v2"
*ShortNickName: "MFC-L3750CDW-v2"
*NickName: "Brother MFC-L3750CDW CUPS v3"
*PSVersion: "(3010.106) 3"

*%==== Basic Device Capabilities =============
*LanguageLevel: "3"
*ColorDevice: True
*DefaultColorSpace: RGB
*FileSystem: False
*Throughput: "17"
*VariablePaperSize: False
*TTRasterizer: Type42
*FreeVM: "2700000"
*DefaultResolution: 600dpi
*%DefaultOutputOrder: Reverse

*%=== UI Constraints ==================================
*UIConstraints: "*BRInputSlot AutoSelect *BRMediaType Label"
*UIConstraints: "*BRInputSlot Tray1 *BRMediaType Label"

*%==== Media Selection ======================
*OpenUI *PageSize/Media Size: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 11 AnySetup *PageSize
*DefaultPageSize: Letter
*PageSize A4/A4:                                       "          "
*PageSize Letter/Letter:                               "          "
*PageSize Legal/Legal:                                 "          "
*PageSize Executive/Executive:                         "          "
*PageSize A5/A5:                                       "          "
*PageSize A5Rotated/A5 Long Edge:                      "          "
*PageSize A6/A6:                                       "          "
*PageSize B5/B5:                                       "          "
*PageSize JISB5/JIS B5:                                "          "
*PageSize JISB6/JIS B6:                                "          "
*PageSize EnvDL/DL:                                    "          "
*PageSize EnvC5/C5:                                    "          "
*PageSize Env10/Com-10:                                "          "
*PageSize EnvMonarch/Monarch:                          "          "
*PageSize Br3x5/3 x 5:                                 "          "
*PageSize CardEnv/Card Envelope 525x725:               "          "
*PageSize FanFoldGermanLegal/Folio:                    "          "
*%PageSize EnvPRC5Rotated/DL Long Edge:                "          "
*PageSize Postcard/Hagaki:                             "          "
*PageSize EnvYou4/Envelope #4:                         "          "
*%PageSize EnvChou3/N3 Envelope:                        "          "
*%PageSize EnvChou4/N4 Envelope:                        "          "
*PageSize 210x270mm/270mm Paper:                       "          "
*PageSize 195x270mm/16K(195x270mm):                    "          "
*%PageSize 184x260mm/16K(184x260mm):                   "          "
*%PageSize 197x273mm/16K(197x273mm):                   "          "
*PageSize MexicanLegal/Mexico Legal:                   "          "
*PageSize IndianLegal/India Legal:                     "          "
*CloseUI: *PageSize

*OpenUI *PageRegion: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 12 AnySetup *PageRegion
*DefaultPageRegion: Letter
*PageRegion A4/A4:                                     "          "
*PageRegion Letter/Letter:                             "          "
*PageRegion Legal/Legal:                               "          "
*PageRegion Executive/Executive:                       "          "
*PageRegion A5/A5:                                     "          "
*PageRegion A5Rotated/A5 Long Edge:                    "          "
*PageRegion A6/A6:                                     "          "
*PageRegion B5/B5:                                     "          "
*PageRegion JISB5/JIS B5:                              "          "
*PageRegion JISB6/JIS B6:                              "          "
*PageRegion EnvDL/DL:                                  "          "
*PageRegion EnvC5/C5:                                  "          "
*PageRegion Env10/Com-10:                              "          "
*PageRegion EnvMonarch/Monarch:                        "          "
*PageRegion Br3x5/3 x 5:                               "          "
*PageRegion CardEnv/Card Envelope 525x725:           "          "
*PageRegion FanFoldGermanLegal/Folio:                  "          "
*%PageRegion EnvPRC5Rotated/DL Long Edge:              "          "
*PageRegion Postcard/Hagaki:                           "          "
*PageRegion EnvYou4/Envelope #4:                       "          "
*%PageRegion EnvChou3/N3 Envelope:                      "          "
*%PageRegion EnvChou4/N4 Envelope:                      "          "
*PageRegion 210x270mm/270mm Paper:                     "          "
*PageRegion 195x270mm/16K(195x270mm):                  "          "
*%PageRegion 184x260mm/16K(184x260mm):                 "          "
*%PageRegion 197x273mm/16K(197x273mm):                 "          "
*PageRegion MexicanLegal/Mexico Legal:                 "          "
*PageRegion IndianLegal/India Legal:                   "          "
*CloseUI: *PageRegion

*DefaultImageableArea: Letter
*ImageableArea A4/A4:                                  "12 12 583 830"
*ImageableArea Letter/Letter:                          "12 12 600 780"
*ImageableArea Legal/Legal:                            "12 12 600 996"
*ImageableArea Executive/Executive:                    "12 12 510 744"
*ImageableArea A5/A5:                                  "12 12 408 583"
*ImageableArea A5Rotated/A5 Long Edge:                 "12 12 583 408"
*ImageableArea A6/A6:                                  "12 12 285 408"
*ImageableArea B5/B5:                                  "12 12 487 697"
*ImageableArea JISB5/JIS B5:                           "12 12 504 717"
*ImageableArea JISB6/JIS B6:                           "12 12 351 504"
*ImageableArea EnvDL/DL:                               "12 12 300 612"
*ImageableArea EnvC5/C5:                               "12 12 447 637"
*ImageableArea Env10/Com-10:                           "12 12 285 672"
*ImageableArea EnvMonarch/Monarch:                     "12 12 267 528"
*ImageableArea Br3x5/3 x 5:                            "12 12 204 348"
*ImageableArea CardEnv/Card Envelope 525x725:          "12 12 354 510"
*ImageableArea FanFoldGermanLegal/Folio:               "12 12 600 924"
*%ImageableArea EnvPRC5Rotated/DL Long Edge:           "18 12 606 300"
*ImageableArea Postcard/Hagaki:                        "12 12 272 407"
*ImageableArea EnvYou4/Envelope #4:                    "12 12 286 654"
*%ImageableArea EnvChou3/N3 Envelop:                    "12 12 328 654"
*%ImageableArea EnvChou4/N4 Envelop:                    "12 12 243 569"
*ImageableArea 210x270mm/270mm Paper:                  "12 12 583 753"
*ImageableArea 195x270mm/16K(195x270mm):               "12 12 541 753"
*%ImageableArea 184x260mm/16K(184x260mm):              "12 12 510 725"
*%ImageableArea 197x273mm/16K(197x273mm):              "12 12 546 762"
*ImageableArea MexicanLegal/Mexico Legal:              "12 12 600 951"
*ImageableArea IndianLegal/India Legal:                "12 12 597 966"

*%==== Information About Media Sizes ========
*DefaultPaperDimension: Letter
*PaperDimension A4/A4:                                 "595 842"
*PaperDimension Letter/Letter:                         "612 792"
*PaperDimension Legal/Legal:                           "612 1008"
*PaperDimension Executive/Executive:                   "522 756"
*PaperDimension A5/A5:                                 "420 595"
*PaperDimension A5Rotated/A5 Long Edge:                "595 420"
*PaperDimension A6/A6:                                 "297 420"
*PaperDimension B5/B5:                                 "499 709"
*PaperDimension JISB5/JIS B5:                          "516 729"
*PaperDimension JISB6/JIS B6:                          "363 516"
*PaperDimension EnvDL/DL:                              "312 624"
*PaperDimension EnvC5/C5:                              "459 649"
*PaperDimension Env10/Com-10:                          "297 684"
*PaperDimension EnvMonarch/Monarch:                    "279 540"
*PaperDimension Br3x5/3 x 5:                           "216 360"
*PaperDimension CardEnv/Card Envelope 525x725:         "378 522"
*PaperDimension FanFoldGermanLegal/Folio:              "612 936"
*%PaperDimension EnvPRC5Rotated/DL Long Edge:          "624 312"
*PaperDimension Postcard/Hagaki:                       "284 419"
*PaperDimension EnvYou4/Envelope #4:                   "298 666"
*%PaperDimension EnvChou3/N3 Envelop:                   "340 666"
*%PaperDimension EnvChou4/N4 Envelop:                   "255 581"         
*PaperDimension 210x270mm/270mm Paper:                 "595 765"
*PaperDimension 195x270mm/16K(195x270mm):              "553 765"
*%PaperDimension 184x260mm/16K(184x260mm):             "522 737"
*%PaperDimension 197x273mm/16K(197x273mm):             "558 774"
*PaperDimension MexicanLegal/Mexico Legal:             "612 963"
*PaperDimension IndianLegal/India Legal:               "609 978"

*%==== Custom Page Sizes ====================
*%NonUIOrderDependency: 40 AnySetup *CustomPageSize
*%VariablePaperSize: True
*%LeadingEdge Short: ""
*%DefaultLeadingEdge: Short
*%MaxMediaWidth: "612"
*%MaxMediaHeight: "1008"
*%HWMargins: 12 12 12 12
*%End
*%ParamCustomPageSize Width: 1 points 216 612
*%ParamCustomPageSize Height: 2 points 329 1008
*%ParamCustomPageSize WidthOffset: 3 points 0 0
*%ParamCustomPageSize HeightOffset: 4 points 0 0
*%ParamCustomPageSize Orientation: 5 int 0 3

*%=== Duplex ================================
*OpenUI *Duplex/Two-Sided: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 25 AnySetup *Duplex
*DefaultDuplex: None
*Duplex DuplexTumble/Short-Edge Binding:         "          "
*Duplex DuplexNoTumble/Long-Edge Binding:        "          "
*Duplex None/Off: "          "
*CloseUI: *Duplex

*%=== Paper Feed================================
*OpenUI *BRInputSlot/Paper Source: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 13 AnySetup *BRInputSlot
*DefaultBRInputSlot: AutoSelect
*BRInputSlot AutoSelect/Auto Select:        "          "
*BRInputSlot Tray1/Tray1:                   "          "
*BRInputSlot Manual/Manual:                 "          "
*CloseUI: *BRInputSlot

*%==== Resolution Features =================================
*OpenUI *BRResolution/Print Quality: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 14 AnySetup *BRResolution
*DefaultBRResolution: 600dpi
*BRResolution 600dpi/Normal:                    "          "
*BRResolution 600x2400dpi/Fine:          "          "
*CloseUI: *BRResolution

*%=== MonoOrColor ================================
*OpenUI *BRMonoColor/Color / Mono: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 16 AnySetup *BRMonoColor
*DefaultBRMonoColor: Auto
*BRMonoColor Auto/Auto:                       "          "
*BRMonoColor FullColor/Color:                 "          "
*BRMonoColor Mono/Mono:                       "          "
*CloseUI: *BRMonoColor

*%=== Media Type ================================
*OpenUI *BRMediaType/Media Type: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 17 AnySetup *BRMediaType
*DefaultBRMediaType: Plain
*BRMediaType Plain/Plain Paper:               "          "
*BRMediaType Thin/Thin Paper:                 "          "
*BRMediaType Thick/Thick Paper:               "          "
*BRMediaType Thicker/Thicker Paper:           "          "
*BRMediaType BOND/Bond Paper:                 "          "
*BRMediaType Env/Envelopes:                   "          "
*BRMediaType EnvThick/Env. Thick:             "          "
*BRMediaType EnvThin/Env. Thin:               "          "
*BRMediaType Recycled/Recycled Paper:         "          "
*BRMediaType Label/Label:                     "          "
*BRMediaType Glossy/Glossy Paper:             "          "
*BRMediaType PostCard/Postcard:               "          "
*CloseUI: *BRMediaType

*%===Color Matching ================================
*OpenUI *BRColorMatching/Color Mode: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 18 AnySetup *BRColorMatching
*DefaultBRColorMatching: Normal
*BRColorMatching Normal/Normal:               "          "
*BRColorMatching Vivid/Vivid:                 "          "
*BRColorMatching None/None:                   "          "
*CloseUI: *BRColorMatching

*%=== Improve Gray Color ================================
*OpenUI *BRGray/Improve Gray Color: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 19 AnySetup *BRGray
*DefaultBRGray: ON
*BRGray OFF/Off:                              "          "
*BRGray ON/On:                                "          "
*CloseUI: *BRGray

*%=== Enhance Black Printing ================================
*OpenUI *BREnhanceBlkPrt/Enhance Black Printing: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 20 AnySetup *BREnhanceBlkPrt
*DefaultBREnhanceBlkPrt: OFF
*BREnhanceBlkPrt OFF/Off:                    "          "
*BREnhanceBlkPrt ON/On:                      "          "
*CloseUI: *BREnhanceBlkPrt


*%=== Toner Save Mode ================================
*OpenUI *BRTonerSaveMode/Toner Save Mode: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 29 AnySetup  *BRTonerSaveMode
*DefaultBRTonerSaveMode: OFF
*BRTonerSaveMode OFF/Off:                     "          "
*BRTonerSaveMode ON/On:                       "          "
*CloseUI: *BRTonerSaveMode

*%=== Improve Print Output ================================
*OpenUI *BRImproveOutput/Improve Print Output: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 30 AnySetup *BRImproveOutput
*DefaultBRImproveOutput: OFF
*BRImproveOutput OFF/Off:                                 "          "
*BRImproveOutput BRLessPaperCurl/Reduce Paper Curl:       "          "
*BRImproveOutput BRFixIntensity/Improve Toner Fixing:     "          "
*CloseUI: *BRImproveOutput

*%==== Sleep Time ============================

*%=== Send Fax ================================

*%=== Skip Blank Page ================================
*OpenUI *BRSkipBlank/Skip Blank Page: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 31 AnySetup *BRSkipBlank
*DefaultBRSkipBlank: OFF
*BRSkipBlank OFF/Off: "          "
*BRSkipBlank ON/On: "          "
*CloseUI: *BRSkipBlank

*%=== Brightness ================================
*OpenUI *BRBrightness/Brightness: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 25 AnySetup *BRBrightness
*DefaultBRBrightness: 0
*BRBrightness -20/-20: "          "
*BRBrightness -19/-19: "          "
*BRBrightness -18/-18: "          "
*BRBrightness -17/-17: "          "
*BRBrightness -16/-16: "          "
*BRBrightness -15/-15: "          "
*BRBrightness -14/-14: "          "
*BRBrightness -13/-13: "          "
*BRBrightness -12/-12: "          "
*BRBrightness -11/-11: "          "
*BRBrightness -10/-10: "          "
*BRBrightness -9/-9: "          "
*BRBrightness -8/-8: "          "
*BRBrightness -7/-7: "          "
*BRBrightness -6/-6: "          "
*BRBrightness -5/-5: "          "
*BRBrightness -4/-4: "          "
*BRBrightness -3/-3: "          "
*BRBrightness -2/-2: "          "
*BRBrightness -1/-1: "          "
*BRBrightness 0/0: "          "
*BRBrightness 1/1: "          "
*BRBrightness 2/2: "          "
*BRBrightness 3/3: "          "
*BRBrightness 4/4: "          "
*BRBrightness 5/5: "          "
*BRBrightness 6/6: "          "
*BRBrightness 7/7: "          "
*BRBrightness 8/8: "          "
*BRBrightness 9/9: "          "
*BRBrightness 10/10: "          "
*BRBrightness 11/11: "          "
*BRBrightness 12/12: "          "
*BRBrightness 13/13: "          "
*BRBrightness 14/14: "          "
*BRBrightness 15/15: "          "
*BRBrightness 16/16: "          "
*BRBrightness 17/17: "          "
*BRBrightness 18/18: "          "
*BRBrightness 19/19: "          "
*BRBrightness 20/20: "          "
*CloseUI: *BRBrightness

*%=== Contrast ================================
*OpenUI *BRContrast/Contrast: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 26 AnySetup *BRContrast
*DefaultBRContrast: 0
*BRContrast -20/-20: "          "
*BRContrast -19/-19: "          "
*BRContrast -18/-18: "          "
*BRContrast -17/-17: "          "
*BRContrast -16/-16: "          "
*BRContrast -15/-15: "          "
*BRContrast -14/-14: "          "
*BRContrast -13/-13: "          "
*BRContrast -12/-12: "          "
*BRContrast -11/-11: "          "
*BRContrast -10/-10: "          "
*BRContrast -9/-9: "          "
*BRContrast -8/-8: "          "
*BRContrast -7/-7: "          "
*BRContrast -6/-6: "          "
*BRContrast -5/-5: "          "
*BRContrast -4/-4: "          "
*BRContrast -3/-3: "          "
*BRContrast -2/-2: "          "
*BRContrast -1/-1: "          "
*BRContrast 0/0: "          "
*BRContrast 1/1: "          "
*BRContrast 2/2: "          "
*BRContrast 3/3: "          "
*BRContrast 4/4: "          "
*BRContrast 5/5: "          "
*BRContrast 6/6: "          "
*BRContrast 7/7: "          "
*BRContrast 8/8: "          "
*BRContrast 9/9: "          "
*BRContrast 10/10: "          "
*BRContrast 11/11: "          "
*BRContrast 12/12: "          "
*BRContrast 13/13: "          "
*BRContrast 14/14: "          "
*BRContrast 15/15: "          "
*BRContrast 16/16: "          "
*BRContrast 17/17: "          "
*BRContrast 18/18: "          "
*BRContrast 19/19: "          "
*BRContrast 20/20: "          "
*CloseUI: *BRContrast

*%=== Red ================================
*OpenUI *BRRed/Red: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 27 AnySetup *BRRed
*DefaultBRRed: 0
*BRRed -20/-20: "          "
*BRRed -19/-19: "          "
*BRRed -18/-18: "          "
*BRRed -17/-17: "          "
*BRRed -16/-16: "          "
*BRRed -15/-15: "          "
*BRRed -14/-14: "          "
*BRRed -13/-13: "          "
*BRRed -12/-12: "          "
*BRRed -11/-11: "          "
*BRRed -10/-10: "          "
*BRRed -9/-9: "          "
*BRRed -8/-8: "          "
*BRRed -7/-7: "          "
*BRRed -6/-6: "          "
*BRRed -5/-5: "          "
*BRRed -4/-4: "          "
*BRRed -3/-3: "          "
*BRRed -2/-2: "          "
*BRRed -1/-1: "          "
*BRRed 0/0: "          "
*BRRed 1/1: "          "
*BRRed 2/2: "          "
*BRRed 3/3: "          "
*BRRed 4/4: "          "
*BRRed 5/5: "          "
*BRRed 6/6: "          "
*BRRed 7/7: "          "
*BRRed 8/8: "          "
*BRRed 9/9: "          "
*BRRed 10/10: "          "
*BRRed 11/11: "          "
*BRRed 12/12: "          "
*BRRed 13/13: "          "
*BRRed 14/14: "          "
*BRRed 15/15: "          "
*BRRed 16/16: "          "
*BRRed 17/17: "          "
*BRRed 18/18: "          "
*BRRed 19/19: "          "
*BRRed 20/20: "          "
*CloseUI: *BRRed

*%=== Green ================================
*OpenUI *BRGreen/Green: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 28 AnySetup *BRGreen
*DefaultBRGreen: 0
*BRGreen -20/-20: "          "
*BRGreen -19/-19: "          "
*BRGreen -18/-18: "          "
*BRGreen -17/-17: "          "
*BRGreen -16/-16: "          "
*BRGreen -15/-15: "          "
*BRGreen -14/-14: "          "
*BRGreen -13/-13: "          "
*BRGreen -12/-12: "          "
*BRGreen -11/-11: "          "
*BRGreen -10/-10: "          "
*BRGreen -9/-9: "          "
*BRGreen -8/-8: "          "
*BRGreen -7/-7: "          "
*BRGreen -6/-6: "          "
*BRGreen -5/-5: "          "
*BRGreen -4/-4: "          "
*BRGreen -3/-3: "          "
*BRGreen -2/-2: "          "
*BRGreen -1/-1: "          "
*BRGreen 0/0: "          "
*BRGreen 1/1: "          "
*BRGreen 2/2: "          "
*BRGreen 3/3: "          "
*BRGreen 4/4: "          "
*BRGreen 5/5: "          "
*BRGreen 6/6: "          "
*BRGreen 7/7: "          "
*BRGreen 8/8: "          "
*BRGreen 9/9: "          "
*BRGreen 10/10: "          "
*BRGreen 11/11: "          "
*BRGreen 12/12: "          "
*BRGreen 13/13: "          "
*BRGreen 14/14: "          "
*BRGreen 15/15: "          "
*BRGreen 16/16: "          "
*BRGreen 17/17: "          "
*BRGreen 18/18: "          "
*BRGreen 19/19: "          "
*BRGreen 20/20: "          "
*CloseUI: *BRGreen

*%=== Blue ================================
*OpenUI *BRBlue/Blue: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 29 AnySetup *BRBlue
*DefaultBRBlue: 0
*BRBlue -20/-20: "          "
*BRBlue -19/-19: "          "
*BRBlue -18/-18: "          "
*BRBlue -17/-17: "          "
*BRBlue -16/-16: "          "
*BRBlue -15/-15: "          "
*BRBlue -14/-14: "          "
*BRBlue -13/-13: "          "
*BRBlue -12/-12: "          "
*BRBlue -11/-11: "          "
*BRBlue -10/-10: "          "
*BRBlue -9/-9: "          "
*BRBlue -8/-8: "          "
*BRBlue -7/-7: "          "
*BRBlue -6/-6: "          "
*BRBlue -5/-5: "          "
*BRBlue -4/-4: "          "
*BRBlue -3/-3: "          "
*BRBlue -2/-2: "          "
*BRBlue -1/-1: "          "
*BRBlue 0/0: "          "
*BRBlue 1/1: "          "
*BRBlue 2/2: "          "
*BRBlue 3/3: "          "
*BRBlue 4/4: "          "
*BRBlue 5/5: "          "
*BRBlue 6/6: "          "
*BRBlue 7/7: "          "
*BRBlue 8/8: "          "
*BRBlue 9/9: "          "
*BRBlue 10/10: "          "
*BRBlue 11/11: "          "
*BRBlue 12/12: "          "
*BRBlue 13/13: "          "
*BRBlue 14/14: "          "
*BRBlue 15/15: "          "
*BRBlue 16/16: "          "
*BRBlue 17/17: "          "
*BRBlue 18/18: "          "
*BRBlue 19/19: "          "
*BRBlue 20/20: "          "
*CloseUI: *BRBlue

*%=== Saturation ================================
*OpenUI *BRSaturation/Saturation: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 29 AnySetup *BRSaturation
*DefaultBRSaturation: 0
*BRSaturation -20/-20: "          "
*BRSaturation -19/-19: "          "
*BRSaturation -18/-18: "          "
*BRSaturation -17/-17: "          "
*BRSaturation -16/-16: "          "
*BRSaturation -15/-15: "          "
*BRSaturation -14/-14: "          "
*BRSaturation -13/-13: "          "
*BRSaturation -12/-12: "          "
*BRSaturation -11/-11: "          "
*BRSaturation -10/-10: "          "
*BRSaturation -9/-9: "          "
*BRSaturation -8/-8: "          "
*BRSaturation -7/-7: "          "
*BRSaturation -6/-6: "          "
*BRSaturation -5/-5: "          "
*BRSaturation -4/-4: "          "
*BRSaturation -3/-3: "          "
*BRSaturation -2/-2: "          "
*BRSaturation -1/-1: "          "
*BRSaturation 0/0: "          "
*BRSaturation 1/1: "          "
*BRSaturation 2/2: "          "
*BRSaturation 3/3: "          "
*BRSaturation 4/4: "          "
*BRSaturation 5/5: "          "
*BRSaturation 6/6: "          "
*BRSaturation 7/7: "          "
*BRSaturation 8/8: "          "
*BRSaturation 9/9: "          "
*BRSaturation 10/10: "          "
*BRSaturation 11/11: "          "
*BRSaturation 12/12: "          "
*BRSaturation 13/13: "          "
*BRSaturation 14/14: "          "
*BRSaturation 15/15: "          "
*BRSaturation 16/16: "          "
*BRSaturation 17/17: "          "
*BRSaturation 18/18: "          "
*BRSaturation 19/19: "          "
*BRSaturation 20/20: "          "
*CloseUI: *BRSaturation



*DefaultFont: Courier
*Font AvantGarde-Book: Standard "(001.006S)" Standard ROM
*Font AvantGarde-BookOblique: Standard "(001.006S)" Standard ROM
*Font AvantGarde-Demi: Standard "(001.007S)" Standard ROM
*Font AvantGarde-DemiOblique: Standard "(001.007S)" Standard ROM
*Font Bookman-Demi: Standard "(001.004S)" Standard ROM
*Font Bookman-DemiItalic: Standard "(001.004S)" Standard ROM
*Font Bookman-Light: Standard "(001.004S)" Standard ROM
*Font Bookman-LightItalic: Standard "(001.004S)" Standard ROM
*Font Courier: Standard "(002.004S)" Standard ROM
*Font Courier-Bold: Standard "(002.004S)" Standard ROM
*Font Courier-BoldOblique: Standard "(002.004S)" Standard ROM
*Font Courier-Oblique: Standard "(002.004S)" Standard ROM
*Font Helvetica: Standard "(001.006S)" Standard ROM
*Font Helvetica-Bold: Standard "(001.007S)" Standard ROM
*Font Helvetica-BoldOblique: Standard "(001.007S)" Standard ROM
*Font Helvetica-Narrow: Standard "(001.006S)" Standard ROM
*Font Helvetica-Narrow-Bold: Standard "(001.007S)" Standard ROM
*Font Helvetica-Narrow-BoldOblique: Standard "(001.007S)" Standard ROM
*Font Helvetica-Narrow-Oblique: Standard "(001.006S)" Standard ROM
*Font Helvetica-Oblique: Standard "(001.006S)" Standard ROM
*Font NewCenturySchlbk-Bold: Standard "(001.009S)" Standard ROM
*Font NewCenturySchlbk-BoldItalic: Standard "(001.007S)" Standard ROM
*Font NewCenturySchlbk-Italic: Standard "(001.006S)" Standard ROM
*Font NewCenturySchlbk-Roman: Standard "(001.007S)" Standard ROM
*Font Palatino-Bold: Standard "(001.005S)" Standard ROM
*Font Palatino-BoldItalic: Standard "(001.005S)" Standard ROM
*Font Palatino-Italic: Standard "(001.005S)" Standard ROM
*Font Palatino-Roman: Standard "(001.005S)" Standard ROM
*Font Times-Bold: Standard "(001.007S)" Standard ROM
*Font Times-BoldItalic: Standard "(001.009S)" Standard ROM
*Font Times-Italic: Standard "(001.007S)" Standard ROM
*Font Times-Roman: Standard "(001.007S)" Standard ROM
*Font ZapfChancery-MediumItalic: Standard "(001.007S)" Standard ROM
*Font ZapfDingbats: Special "(001.004S)" Special ROM
*Font Symbol: Special "(001.007S)" Special ROM
*Font Alaska: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font AlaskaExtrabold: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font AntiqueOakland: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font AntiqueOakland-Bold: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font AntiqueOakland-Oblique: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font ClevelandCondensed: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Connecticut: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Guatemala-Antique: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Guatemala-Bold: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Guatemala-Italic: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Guatemala-BoldItalic: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font LetterGothic: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font LetterGothic-Bold: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font LetterGothic-Oblique: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Maryland: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Oklahoma: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Oklahoma-Bold: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Oklahoma-Oblique: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Oklahoma-BoldOblique: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Utah: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Utah-Bold: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Utah-Oblique: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Utah-BoldOblique: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font UtahCondensed: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font UtahCondensed-Bold: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font UtahCondensed-Oblique: Standard "(001.004)" Standard ROM
*Font UtahCondensed-BoldOblique: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font BermudaScript: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font Germany: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font SanDiego: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM
*Font US-Roman: Standard "(001.005)" Standard ROM


Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Click on Menu ----> Format ----> Page Style ----> Page and click on + or - of Width or Height and it appears in Format --- User.
Set up the page, save it as a template, and use it for your envelopes.
